# Function App - Swagger URL shows 404 after deployment to Azure

Tags: azure-functions, swagger, http-status-code-404, openai-api

I am following the following documentation to OPI documentation for my function using Open API Spec

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/openapi-core.md

During debugging on my local machine, the Swagger works fine under the local URL:
http://localhost:7072/api/swagger/ui

However, once I deploy the function app, I am getting a 404 error when I try using the function URL:
https://**********.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger/ui

Any idea what could be wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved using the following changes

- Added reference to Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi
- Followed the instructions in https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/openapi-in-proc.md